# Why isn't Hydrogen used as fuel in Internal combustion engine?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

I was looking at hydrogen cars and found out that hydrogen is mainly used in hydrogen cells to produce electricity instead of combusting it like gasoline in a cylinder to produce heat energy.
Why isn't that done, when it can produce much more Horse power?

Comment: did you try searching google? see http://www.popularmechanics.com/science/energy/a926/4199381/ and http://phys.org/news/2006-12-hydrogen-economy-doesnt.html

Comment: Hi Khaled. This is really an engineering question and [the sort of thing you should research yourself](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=hydrogen%20fuel%20cell%20vs%20combustion%20engine). If there are specific issues to do with physics then please post another question here.

Comment: The short-short answer is "they are, in the lab". Several automobile companies have built demonstration models and there are a very small number of fueling station. They haven't made their way into "real" life for engineering and economic reasons, not physics ones.

Answer (score 0):

Hydrogen is exceptionally hard to store (it takes much space if just compressed, soaks right even through metal, it must be extremely cold to be liquified). So it is not a viable alternative to hydrocarbon fuels for combustion engines.

By using it in a fuel cell, which converts the stored energy with a higher efficiency, makes it more favorable even if the storage is complicated and expensive.

So using hydrogen just makes more sense with fuel cell conversion, and maybe would be economically feasable by one day.